# Can “men” sound like “mint”?

Tags: pronunciation

I know that “men” sounds like “Ben” and nothing else. But I heard First Lady Michelle talked in [this video](https://youtu.be/YypEpohZCRw) around 7:00, she said **men** like **min(t)**. It makes me nervous. Is it true in everyday conversation or is it just her style of speaking?

Comment: Why would this make you nervous? North America is a big place; people from Massachusetts say things a lot differently than people from Alabama; people Wisconsin sound a little different than people from Texas, Saskatchewan, or Ontario. People from Ireland and Australia have their own accents, too. If you think we all sound alike, you need to listen more. Listen to how mmdills22 says the word on [this Forvo page](https://forvo.com/word/men/#en). I don't know of any word in English that sounds like "nothing else," because no two speakers sound exactly alike.

Comment: I suspect that if Michelle Obama said exactly those words several times over, she might only very rarely include that slight "hiatus" (a **/t/**, **/d/** glottal stop, or whatever it is). My guess is it's mostly an "artefact" primarily caused by the fact that she needs to introduce pauses sometimes to draw breath while speaking, not because she finds it "natural" to have that little break between ***men*** and ***everywhere***, which *might* be more likely simply because ***everywhere*** starts with a vowel sound (or because she wants to *emphasise* it more).

Comment: @J.R. It makes me nervous because it differs so much from what I know and I’ve looked the pronunciation. By saying “nothing else” I mean I could understand that the sound differs a little with each person, but not that much from what I’ve found.

Comment: @user67265 Understanding other accents than you were raised with (or learn with), is something every native speaker has to contend with. I personally have a very different accent compared to where I live now - some people here struggle to understand me, despite us all being native speakers. Don't worry yourself with understanding all english speakers - just worry about understanding enough of them (e.g. textbook American/British), you can guess what the rest meant.